# get all first occurences of a column based on the value of another column - matlab

Tags: matlab, unique

```
m = repmat([0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2;11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33],1,2)'
```

I'm trying to get *all* *first* occurrences of `m(:,1)` when `m(:,2)==11`
In my example I would like to retrieve the vector :

```
 0  (from row 1, because it's the first occurrence of (0,11))
 1  (from row 7, because it's the first occurrence of (1,11))
 2  (from row 13, because it's the first occurrence of (2,11))
 0  (from row 19, because it's the next first occurrence of (0,11))
 1  (from row 25, because it's the next first occurrence of (1,11))
 2  (from row 31, because it's the next first occurrence of (2,11))
```

I thought `unique` might be the function for this but `unique(m(:,1),'rows')` ignores repeated values

```
ans =

     0
     1
     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way:

```
indx_11 = find(m(:,2) == 11);
% Find all the places where change occurs which will miss the 1st element
indxDiff = (diff(m(:,1))~=0); 
% Include the 1st element
m(intersect(find([1; indxDiff]), indx_11),1);
```

It works for the following vector too.

```
m1 = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2; ...
11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33,11,11,22,22,33,33]';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to get it without `for` loop:

```
a = find(m(:, 2) == 11); % index for all 11
repeat = [false; diff(a)==1]; % true if index diff is one
a(repeat) = []; % remove those indices for non-first occurrence
result = m(a, 1); % what you want
```